# String Encode, Array Decode

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP, I started about 3 weeks ago.

I have a string, which is used with $_POST to pass it to another page, the second page uses $_GET to get these url and split it as desired.

My problem is that, in my first page I use a String, and I want to encrypt it, so that I can pass it as a plan text. In the second page I must decrypt it and get it as an array.

So is there any encryption method or function I can use which is compatible with $_POST ( so I can send it to another page ) and decrypt it as an array ?

I need this method, because the second page is actually connecting to website and is a payment method. So i don't want users to manually edit the url and lower the amount of $ for the product they get.

tnx for your help.

Comment: $_POST is used to receive parameters sent to the server using a POST request, in which the parameters are passed in the body of the request, usually URL-encoded (e.g. via a form submission or an ajax request). $_GET is actually the same concept, except for the fact that the parameters are located in the request URL (e.g. www.domain.tld?param1=value1&param2=value2&...)

Comment: Note that a user always can change the values of the request.. it's just a question of the users knowledge of the HTTP protocol. So you should really never pass such information along with the requests.

Comment: use sessions. encrypting can be often subverted by someone more experienced than you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you probably want to do is pass the contents of the users cart (i.e. the items he'd like to order) to the payment site.
Therefore, you should create a form like:

```
<form action="URL/to/paymentPage.php" method="post">
<!-- Item 1 -->
<input type="hidden" name="items[0]" value="productID1"/>
<input type="hidden" name="quantity[0]" value="quantity1"/>
<!-- Item 2 -->
<input type="hidden" name="items[1]" value="productID2"/>
<input type="hidden" name="quantity[1]" value="quantity2"/>
<!-- ... -->
<!-- Item n -->
<input type="hidden" name="items[n]" value="productIDn"/>
<input type="hidden" name="quantity[n]" value="quantityn"/>

<input type="submit" value="Order"/>
</form>
```

On the server in the file "URL/to/paymentPage.php" you can access the items using the following code:

```
<?php
$items = $_POST['items']; // Array of items ..
$quantities = $_POST['quantity']; // The array of quantities for each item ..

// Calculate the total price ..
$totalPrice = 0;
foreach($items as $idx => $itemID) {
  if($quantities[$idx]>0) {
    totalPrice += getPriceFromDB($itemID) * $quantities[$idx];
  }
}

echo 'Total Price to pay: '.$totalPrice;
?>
```

where the function getPriceFromDB actually retrieves the price for the item/product with the id $itemID from your database or elsewhere... :)

However, the user items are usually stored in the session, and, therefore, there is no need to submit the again.. ;)

Answer (score 3):

You're thinking about this wrong. You NEVER trust information coming from the user's side.

For example, if your user sends a form that says what item they want, DO NOT include the price in the form. Instead, get the price from the server (database), where it can be trusted.

Comment: I forgot to mention this, but of course, you're absolutely right

Comment: @user1391170, If you need to use data from one page on another, stick it in `$_SESSION`.  Session data is stored server-side, and a session ID cookie is stored with the client.

Answer (score 0):

Despite not fully understanding what you're trying to achieve, you can use base64 encoding:

```
$encoded_string = base64_encode ($string);

$decoded_string = base64_decode ($encoded_string);
```

Comment: Base64 is not a crypto. It's easily viewable and editable by almost everyone knowing anything at all about programming.

Comment: Yes, Emil, but why would that be a problem? He just wants to pass it as plain text, and that can be done using base64

Comment: From the question: "and I want to encrypt it" and "i don't want users to manually edit the url and lower the amount"